# Grafana - how to alarm on a not declining metric?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

Is there a way to configure a Grafana alert on a metric to trigger when the value of the metric is not declining over a period of time?

I'm tracking the size of a queue and would like to know when it's stuck.

This is healthy:
[image]
This is not healthy:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a query like this:

```
delta(metric_name[1m])
```

Then set the Alert Config to count_non_null() has no value:

[image: Grapha Alerts]